# Insert Multiple Rows from 2 table into 1 table with PrimaryKey

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables,

Table A header and A Details as a master

Table C header and C Details as a transaction

for example :

```
Table A Header
|Aid | Desc | UnitCost
|1   | Ts   | 1400

Table A Detail
Aid |BID  | Qty | UnitCost
1   |1    | 12  | 200
1   |2    | 21  | 300
1   |3    | 33  | 400
```

then, i got the insert process for table C as a transaction, include a detail :

```
Table C header
CID |Desc
1   |Payment Transaction
```

the detail transaction as follow:

I want to insert Table A header and Table A Detail into table c detail (How to Get this?)

```
Table C detail
CID |BID  | Qty | UnitCost
1   |1    |  1  | 1400
1   |1    | 12  | 0
1   |2    | 21  | 0
1   |3    | 33  | 0
```

i already create an insert process like this (below), but it give me an error.

and i want to make unitcost = 0 for the Table A Detail.

```
INSERT INTO TableCHeader (CID, Desc) VALUES (1, 'Payment Transactions')

-- insert table A header first
INSERT INTO TableCDetail (CID, BID, Qty, UnitCost)
VALUES (1, (SELECT AID, 1, UnitCost FROM TableAHeader WHERE AID = 1))

-- then, insert table A details
INSERT INTO TableCDetail (CID, BID, Qty, UnitCost)
VALUES (1, (SELECT BID, Qty, UnitCost FROM TableADetail WHERE AID = 1))
```

is there anyway I can get the result?

Comment: *it gave me an error* what error? Knowing the error is a great start to helping get to the solution

Comment: What is the PK for table C-Detail ?  Why two entries for CID=1 & BID=1?  Why not change the summary to BID=0 ?  Then you know for Each CID that BID >=1 came from A-Detail, and BID=0 is the summary of the UnitCost for the CID value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer will be like this:

```
;WITH Table_A_Header AS
(
    SELECT 1  Aid , 'Ts' AS [Desc], 1400 AS UnitCost
)
,Table_A_Detail AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Aid,1 AS BID,12 AS Qty,200 AS UnitCost
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,2,21,300
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,3,33,400
)
--INSERT INTO TableCDetail (CID, BID, Qty, UnitCost)
SELECT 
    CID=1,
    BID=AID,
    QTY=1, 
    UnitCost 
FROM Table_A_Header WHERE AID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    CID=1,
    BID, 
    Qty, 
    UnitCost=0
FROM Table_A_Detail WHERE AID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your latter part should be like

```
-- insert table A header first
INSERT INTO TableCDetail (CID, BID, Qty, UnitCost)
SELECT 
    CID=1,
    BID=AID,
    QTY=1, 
    UnitCost 
FROM TableAHeader WHERE AID = 1

-- then, insert table A details
INSERT INTO TableCDetail (CID, BID, Qty, UnitCost)
SELECT
    CID=1,
    BID, 
    Qty, 
    UnitCost=0
FROM TableADetail WHERE AID = 1
```

Comment: Thank you.. this is correct, but for the first insert statement, i get the double record.